# Wide character in subroutine entry when using LWP with NTLM authentication

Tags: perl, ntlm, lwp, lwp-useragent

I'm trying to get LWP to work against an IIS server configured with NTLM authentication. When NTLM authentication is turned off on the server, the code work fine, so I assume that the only problem here is the NTLM authentication.

So far, I have the following:

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(agent => "whatever",
                            timeout => $timeout, keep_alive => 1);
$ua->credentials('hostname:80', '', $username, $password);

my $hdr = HTTP::Headers->new("Content-Type" => "text/xml; charset=UTF-8",
                             "SOAPAction" => "\"whatever\"");

my $req = HTTP::Request->new("POST" => $url, $hdr, encode_utf8($post));
$res = $ua->request($req);
```

If I turn on debugging, I get the following messages:

```
LWP::UserAgent::new: ()
LWP::UserAgent::request: ()
LWP::UserAgent::send_request: POST http://hostname
LWP::UserAgent::_need_proxy: Not proxied
LWP::Protocol::http::request: ()
LWP::Protocol::http::request: Keep the http connection to hostname:80
LWP::UserAgent::request: Simple response: Unauthorized
LWP::Authen::Ntlm::authenticate: authenticate() has been called
Use of uninitialized value in exists at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5/LWP/UserAgent.pm line 560.
Use of uninitialized value in hash element at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5/LWP/UserAgent.pm line 561.
LWP::Authen::Ntlm::authenticate: In first phase of NTLM authentication
[Thu Apr 12 13:55:28 2012] [error] Wide character in subroutine entry at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.5/Authen/NTLM.pm line 346.\n
LWP::Protocol::collect: read 625 bytes
LWP::UserAgent::request: Simple response: Internal Server Error
```

Trying to access the same URL with `wget` works fine. The documentation for [`MIME::Base64`](https://metacpan.org/module/MIME%3a%3aBase64) says that the encode function will croak with `Wide character in subroutine entry` if $bytes contains characters with code above 255.

Am I missing something essential here, or could this be a bug in [`Authen::NTLM`](https://metacpan.org/module/Authen%3a%3aNTLM)?

Comment: I notice the docs for `LWP::Authen::Ntlm` says *The module takes advantage of the Authen::NTLM module by Mark Bush.  Since there 
is also another Authen::NTLM module available from CPAN by Yee Man Chan with an 
entirely different interface, it is necessary to ensure that you have the correct 
NTLM module.* Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: @Borodin: the module lists Mark Bush in the Author section. I also installed the specific version required in LWP - I had Authen::NTLM 1.09, but the version of LWP I'm using required 1.02, but get the same error.

Comment: Hi Vetle :) Do your `$username` or `$password` contain non-ascii characters by any chance?

Comment: Hi Cosimo! :D I double checked, since I originally copy/pasted them, and typed them in once more - still no worky. Checking further, I noticed I had to add a \ to the username, to get LWP::Authen::Ntlm to pass the username to Authen::NTLM (it expects `domain\username`). That got me fewer messages about uninitialized values, but same error message in the end.

Comment: @vetler: any chance your username or password is > 14 chars?

Comment: @EdwardThomson they're both < 14 characters

Answer (score -1):

What is in $post? Maybe is is contain bad data.

Try this:

```
my $post_encoded = encode_utf8($post);
print Dumper($post,$post_encoded);
my $req = HTTP::Request->new("POST" => $url, $hdr, $post_encoded);
```

Comment: I tried replacing `$post_encoded` with 'asdasd', and get the same error message. I've tested this with NTLM authentication turned off on the server, and it works fine. The NTML authentication process *should* be independent on whatever I want to post, as it happens in separate HTTP requests.

Comment: encode_utf8 is not only convert a string to utf-8, it will set the utf-8 flag on it. This way the perl internals know that it is contain an utf-8 value. Or you could try out the opposite way and use decode_utf8.

Comment: This is irrelevant. I've replaced $post_encoded with 'asdasd' (without doing any encoding at all), and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score -4):

Just use curl

```
curl --ntlm -u 'username:password' url
```

Comment: Thanks, but not really helpful. ;) Wget also works fine, but I need this to work with LWP.